# Will I break anything by changing HOME to /Users/flname/Dropbox

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, dropbox, zsh

I have two computers and I want to just turn them on and have the same experience on both.  I *think* the best way to do this is to have my preferences files in my Dropbox.  Problem is, my applications mostly look for preferences in my home directory, which Dropbox doesn't sync (and it seems iCloud doesn't sync hidden files?)

My idea...maybe very stupid...is to change the environment variable in zsh from /Users/flname to /Users/flname/Dropbox.

Can anyone with more experience than me tell me whether this is misguided?

edit: someone asked which applications I'm using...mainly emacs, but theoretically others at some point too.

Comment: What kind of applications are you looking at? GUI applications get their preferences from ~/Library, independent of the value of HOME.

Comment: I admit, this is intriging to see if it can be done, but there's one pitfall that you should be aware of.  Since you are, by definition, trying to mirror your experience across two computers, if for whatever reason, you totally hose up one machine, you will mirror that disaster to the other.  If both machines are running and syncing in real time, you'll hose both of them up spectacularly, in real time. Leaving you with no machines.

Comment: @Allan yes, this sounds like my style -- "todo en el la cama, o todo en el piso"

Comment: I’ve heard that before (as a kid in Miami)...but I always say  [*Así es la vida*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_happens)